# How can I differentiate, in my C/C++ code, between GCC and clang as the compiler?

Tags: gcc, clang, c-preprocessor

I usually write GCC-targeted code by checking `__GNUC__`. Now I want to write some code which behaves differently for GCC and for clang - but it seems clang defines `__GNUC__` as well. How do I differentiate between them?

Comment: This is not such a difficult question, but somehow it seems it hasn't been asked before here on SO.

Answer (score 2):

While both define `__GNUC__`, only clang defines `__clang__`.

So, for GCC-only, you would write:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
// do GCC-only stuff
#endif
```

and of course you could adapt this to GCC-only, clang-only and other, by separating the two conditions.

Note: This is the same for C and for C++.